# Authorization header is not recieving in Aws ECS through ALB

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, jwt, amazon-ecs, aws-application-load-balancer

My project is using jwt token to authenticate request and it is deployed on AWS which uses ECS with farget service. When I send the request with Authorization header from postman then ECS service is not getting the authorization header which block my flow but other unsecure apis are working in ECS from my postman.

cloudwatch screenshot

[image]

postman request screenshot

[image]

what am i missing and how to fix this issue?

I am expecting authorization header with token in ecs cloudwatch

Comment: It seems from your logs that your API is behind a CloudFront distribution and its dropping the Authorization header so its not reaching your origin (API).

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be your answer.
(Look under Configuring CloudFront to forward the Authorization header)
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/add-origin-custom-headers.html#add-origin-custom-headers-forward-authorization

Comment: Thank you so much. It is seems like a road block for me. Now it is working.